# Passing additional arguments to trigger from application

Tags: java, mysql, orm

Is it possible to send additional arguments to trigger in mysql from application?

I have trigger that, before deleting the row in table insert it in table that archives it.

Lets say i have

```
car_rental
id | customer | date_of_rent |
```

and

```
car_rental_archive
id | customer | date_of_rent | date_of_return | demaged
```

the `car_rental_archive` has same columns as the `car_rental` plus `date_of_returned` and `demaged`

I can use trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_car_rental_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `car_rental`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO car_rental_archive(
        customer, date_of_rent, date_of_return, demaged
    ) VALUES(
        OLD.user, OLD.date_of_rent, NOW(), ???
    );
END
```

The `demaged` attribute should be somehow inserted as argument from application. Is something like this possible or do i have to deal with this from application - not using triggers for this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the data is not anywhere in the database you cannot access it in a trigger. So if the `damage` data is new information, it is unfortunately not possible to receive these values within a trigger.

However if you do have these values somewhere in your database already, you can make SELECT statements as usual and select them from a different table.